# How can i create an async function?

Tags: c#, c++

I have several member functions inside my C++ class which i packaged them as a dll 
and tried to used them in a C# application.
I tried to create two async functions by simply executing them using threads and then detaching them() so that they wouldn't block the caller thread till they end.
in C++ based application whenever i use threads to call functions this way, they work, but when i tried to call one of my async functions from c#, my app either crashed or hangs!!
these are my so called async functions!:

```
void xGramManipulator::CreateMonoGramAsync()
{
    thread t(&xGramManipulator::ReadMonoGram, this);
    t.detach();
}

void xGramManipulator::CreateBiGramAsync()
{
    thread t = thread(&xGramManipulator::ReadBiGram, this);
    t.detach();
}
```

And this is the wrapper function in c which resides in a dll :

```
//header
CDLL_API void CreateMonoGramAsync(void);
//cpp
CDLL_API void CreateMonoGramAsync(void)
{
    xG.CreateMonoGramAsync();
}
```

and this is the c# application calling that function :

```
 private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
        CreateBiGramAsync();
        CreateMonoGramAsync();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
     }

}
```

What should i do to have a truly async and non blocking member functions in my class? 
What am i missing here?

Comment: How are you importing these functions in C#?

Comment: obviously - please show the exact code

Comment: [DllImport("CDll.dll")]
public static extern void CreateMonoGramAsync();

Comment: The most likely issue is your import as per the answer from @J... If you want to use tasks rather than threads you could use create_task([this]() { /* Your background code here */ }); Be sure to #include<ppltasks.h> and using namespace concurrency;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are not specifying the calling convention when importing these into C# - by default C# will use `stdcall` while C++ will export as `cdecl`.  You would have to :

```
[DllImport("CDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void CreateMonoGramAsync();
```

alternatively, you can of course specify `returntype __stdcall` when declaring your methods in C++.  I'm also assuming you've otherwise declared the function properly (with `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks now the error is gone! but surprisingly they get executed but doesnt do anything it seems! since when those two functions are executed , upon finishing they each create a file containing their results.!! their normal versions do so but these async seems not!:-/

Comment: @Hossein  I'm afraid I can't really suggest much more without actually seeing the code.  You should probably post a new question on this topic.

Comment: What else should be posted! its all there! if you could elaborate more i would be grateful.

Comment: @Hossein - the C++ code for `xGramManipulator::ReadMonoGram`, etc.  At first glance, however, it seems like you are importing non static member methods as static (which won't work - `this` is an instance of your class which does not exist in a static method).

Comment: I dont get it! i call all of my member functions through a global object inside my cdll.cpp.!so this should point to a valid object since if it doesnt, it must'nt have executed in first place!!

Comment: @Hossein - yes, you don't get it and we can't see your code so we don't get it either.  This question is really a number of questions all rolled into one.  I think we've sorted out the "How do I call a C++ dll function in C#" part, I suggest you start another question with the rest.  Including as much debug information as possible would be helpful.

Comment: Ok Thanks i'll be creating a new question with all that is needed.Thanks for everything Dear J... so far :)

Comment: i created another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949913/problems-with-calling-and-using-c-async-member-functions-from-a-dll-in-a-c-sha

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.5, you could use the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class in order to achieve an asynchronous method call.

Consider the following example:

```
    static void Foo()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo called asynchronously!");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bar = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Foo(); });

        Console.WriteLine("Called synchronously!");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Whenever this code executes, an asynchronous call to `Foo()` will be started, which waits two seconds, and then writes `Foo called asynchronously!` to the console. The other `Console.WriteLine` call is synchronous, and is run right after the asynchronous call has been started.

The output would be:

```
Called synchronously!
Foo called asynchronously!
```

Since the caller's thread isn't blocked by the call to `Foo()`.

You could do the same with your code, and you could even remove the threading you currently have in your methods to make them asynchronous. Reason being is that even though they create their own thread, the .NET runtime is still going to wait for those functions to return. You would be better off calling them like so:

`Task.Factory.StartNew(CreateBiGramAsync());`

That way they'll actually be called asynchronously from .NET itself, and they won't block the caller thread.

Comment: Thanks but I want my functions to be async by default from c++. i am creating a library

Comment: Alright, well your question said that they work fine in C++, but you had trouble calling them asynchronously from C#. Have you tried keeping your C++ functions the way they are and calling them from C# using the `Task` class? I think that will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: I already have two versions , one the ordinary one that can be used normally or by c# threading. and the other version which is async by default and user doesnt need to do anything thing. i believe we have lots of samples in networking libraries which have  such behavior